# Stuck with tvOS and Focus Guides

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tvos

I'm really stuck with this issue.  I'm trying to add a button on top of an AVPlayerViewController that says "Skip Intro" (similar to the button that Netflix has on their content).

I've added 4 or 5 buttons horizontally starting just above the left side of the seek bar and each button are spaced about 10 points apart.  I only need 1 button, but at this point I cannot figure out why I can't click any of these buttons at all:

[image]

I've declared the button and the focus guide variables as private:

[image]

Here's the viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.avPlayerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:self.avPlayerViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.avPlayerViewController.view];
    self.avPlayerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

    self.avPlayerViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    
    NSLayoutConstraint *height =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.avPlayerViewController.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0];
    
    NSLayoutConstraint *width =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.avPlayerViewController.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0];
    
    NSLayoutConstraint *top =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.avPlayerViewController.view
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:self.view
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                           multiplier:1.0
                                                             constant:0.0];
    
    NSLayoutConstraint *leading =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.avPlayerViewController.view
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.view
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:0.0];
    
    [self.view addConstraint:height];
    [self.view addConstraint:width];
    [self.view addConstraint:top];
    [self.view addConstraint:leading];
    
    [self.avPlayerViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self setupBreakButtonWithWidth:225 height:50 xCoordinate:100 yCoordinate:850];
    [self setupBreakButtonWithWidth:225 height:50 xCoordinate:335 yCoordinate:850];
    [self setupBreakButtonWithWidth:225 height:50 xCoordinate:570 yCoordinate:850];
    [self setupBreakButtonWithWidth:225 height:50 xCoordinate:805 yCoordinate:850];
    
    [self setupFocusGuide];
    [self createBannerAdView];
    [self resetUpNextState];
}
```

As you can see, I'm just adding buttons to the bottom of the screen (above the seek bar) and then I setup the focus guide and the preferredFocusEnvironments:

```
- (NSArray<id<UIFocusEnvironment>> *)preferredFocusEnvironments {

    NSLog(@"**** BMNativeVideoPlayerViewController -> preferredFocusEnvironments");
    return @[self.skipBreakButton];
}

- (void)setupFocusGuide
{
    NSLog(@"**** BMNativeVideoPlayerViewController -> setupFocusGuide");
     
    // allocate focus guide and add it to the view
    self.focusGuide = [[UIFocusGuide alloc] init];
    [self.view addLayoutGuide:self.focusGuide];
     
    // define constraints
    [self.focusGuide.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.focusGuide.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor].active = YES;
    
    [self.focusGuide.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_skipBreakButton.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.focusGuide.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_skipBreakButton.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    
    // select the default focusable view
    self.focusGuide.preferredFocusEnvironments = @[self.skipBreakButton];
}
```

Here is the method where the button is configured, along with the button handler method and the didUpdateFocusInContext method (although I don't know if it's doing what it's supposed to):

```
- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    self.focusGuide.preferredFocusEnvironments = @[self.skipBreakButton];
}

- (void)setupBreakButtonWithWidth:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height xCoordinate:(CGFloat)x yCoordinate:(CGFloat)y
{
    NSLog(@"**** BMNativeVideoPlayerViewController -> setupBreakButton");
    _skipBreakButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    _skipBreakButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.skipBreakButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _skipBreakButton.alpha = 1.0f;
    _skipBreakButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    
    _skipBreakButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.avPlayerViewController.contentOverlayView addSubview:_skipBreakButton];
    [self.avPlayerViewController.contentOverlayView bringSubviewToFront:_skipBreakButton];
    
    NSLayoutConstraint *xConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                       constraintWithItem:_skipBreakButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                       NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:x];
    
    NSLayoutConstraint *yConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                       constraintWithItem:_skipBreakButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                       NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:y];
    
    NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_skipBreakButton
                                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                          toItem:nil
                                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                                        constant:width];
    
    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_skipBreakButton
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:nil
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                                         constant:height];
    
    [self.view addConstraints:@[xConstraint, yConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint]];
    [self.skipBreakButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.skipBreakButton setTitle:@"Skip Intro" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.skipBreakButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:26.0]];
    
    NSLog(@"**** Can the skip break button be focused? %d", self.skipBreakButton.canBecomeFocused);
    
    [self.skipBreakButton addTarget:self action:@selector(skipBreakButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered];
}

- (void)skipBreakButtonClicked:(UIButton *) sender {
    NSLog(@"**** BMNativeVideoPlayerViewController -> skipBreakButtonClicked");
}
```

I cannot click on any of these buttons.  I need help to figure out how to get it to work.

It seems that a view is on top of this button but I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
(lldb) po [UIFocusDebugger checkFocusabilityForItem: 0x7ff86fe60510]
The following issues were found that would prevent this item from being focusable:
 - ISSUE: One or more ancestors have issues that may be preventing this item from being focusable. Details:
    <_AVPlayerViewControllerContainerView 0x7ff86fc29eb0>:
         - ISSUE: This view returns YES from -canBecomeFocused, which will prevent its subviews from being focusable.
```

Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayer view controller steals all of the view inputs when it is full screen. In my experience what you have to do is keep the player 1 pixel smaller than the full screen when you have your custom elements and then when your custom elements aren't on the screen you can make it full size. If you set breakpoints in your focus override code you will see that it doesn't hit and this is because Apple is controlling the inputs on their AVPlayerViewController.

If you try the above it should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this behaviour by presenting a modal view controller (with a skip button on it) as overlay over the context of the player.

You can then dismiss the modal view controller after a few seconds (as done in the example below), or programatically if you know when the intro actually finishes.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ThePlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        play(stream: URL(string: "https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/img_bipbop_adv_example_ts/master.m3u8")!)
        presentSkipOverlay()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private
    
    private func play(stream: URL) {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: stream)
        let playetItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playetItem)
        player?.play()
    }
    
    private func presentSkipOverlay() {
        let skipOverlayViewController = SkipOverlayViewController()
        
        skipOverlayViewController.onSkip = {
            [weak self] in
            
            // Skip the intro here
            self?.player?.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: 60.0, preferredTimescale: 1))
        }
        
        skipOverlayViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        skipOverlayViewController.accessibilityViewIsModal = true
        present(skipOverlayViewController, animated: true, completion: {

            // Dismiss the overlay automatically after 3 seconds
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                skipOverlayViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And this would be a naive implementation of the Overlay view controller:

```
final class SkipOverlayViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var onSkip: (() -> Void)?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpView()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private
    
    private lazy var skipButton: UIButton = {
        let skipButton = UIButton()
        skipButton.backgroundColor = .white
        skipButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        skipButton.setTitle("Skip Intro", for: .normal)
        skipButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(skipButtonWasPressed), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        return skipButton
    }()
    
    private func setUpView() {
        view.addSubview(skipButton)
        
        skipButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        skipButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        skipButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -200).isActive = true
        skipButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 225).isActive = true
    }
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    
    @objc
    func skipButtonWasPressed() {
        print("Skip button was Pressed")
        onSkip?()
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]